# Create GIF image with ArrayList<Bitmap>

Tags: android, animated-gif

I have to capture multiple images from camera, convert it into .gif file and show it to the view
below is the code that converts the ArrayList to byte[].

```
 public byte[] generateGIF(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
    encoder.finish();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Now in which I could show it and how

Comment: see `android.graphics.Movie`

Comment: @pskink I have to show byte[] on the view

Comment: did you see `Movie#decodeByteArray` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can show Animated GIF using `Glide`.

```
Glide.with(GIFViewActivity.this)
     .load(byteList.get(0))
     .asGif()
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .into(imageViewGIF);
```